# aws cognito invalidate token on logout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I wasn't able to find clarity on the question, but I know JWT tokens are self contained with its own expiration. Typically, a blacklist could contain "expired" tokens and prevent access to a route if the token is listed there.

I wanted to know that if using aws cognito, and calling the logout endpoint, does that actually blacklist the JWT token on aws side? There is an access token and a refresh token, so do both get invalidated or could a user still login with the token until the expiration time in the token is reached?

Answer (score 3):

No it does not. Calling the LogOut endpoint will invalidate any session you had with the Hosted UI/ Oauth endpoints.

Another option is to call globalSignOut [1] and this will invalidate all of the users Access and Refresh tokens (being used against the Cognito API).

However, the JWT tokens are still valid and as you mentioned, are self contained. There is no built in black listing of tokens that your own servers could check, in a scaleable fashion. This is something you would need to implement yourself if desired.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GlobalSignOut.html

Comment: If the globalSignOut invalidates the tokens, then how are the JWT still valid for use?

Comment: The tokens are invalidated when used against the Cognito service. So trying to refresh the tokens with the refresh token or trying to update a users attributes with their access token will fail. However, if you sent the JWT to an external server for authorisation, the token is self contained so will still be valid until the token expired.

Comment: @callo Is it possible to sign out only one active session? calling the GlobalSignout will end all active sessions of the user and i need to signout from only one session where he clicks logout.

Comment: @Srs To 'sign out' from a device, you can simply delete the tokens and remove any 'session' on that device. This is what the SDKs will do by default if you do not specify the globalSignOut option.

Comment: @callo can you specify which sdk api i should use to achieve the same from the documentation? Thanks in advance. And is there any info i need to get from the client app?

Comment: @Srs Upon further reading, a few months ago cognito release a new feature which allows you to sign out a single session: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/06/amazon-cognito-now-supports-targeted-sign-out-through-refresh-token-revocation/

The amplify SDK appears to already support this functionality: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js/#sign-out

Diving deeper in the SDK, you can see the same here:
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/f1dc4a24330bb41295621aaf47f6c4e26828fea5/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js/src/CognitoUser.js#L1967

Comment: @callo i am not using amplify but java aws sdk and these api endpoints: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html

I found a revoke refresh token api but i am not sure if i can use this for my scenario(I am new to tokens and i have basic knowledge. sorry if its a silly question) :https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_RevokeToken.html

Comment: Hi @Srs yes that would be the API call to make. After that you can remove any existence of your users session in your java application.

Comment: @callo after i make that api call, do i need to do anything else? you said remove users session in the app. how do i do that. wont cognito manager all the sessions?